# Click button on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How can I click a button field using the blackberry api? I'd like to mimic pressing a button as if the user pressed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EventInjector.NavigationEvent` like this:

```
EventInjector.invokeEvent(new EventInjector.NavigationEvent(EventInjector.Navig ationEvent.NAVIGATION_CLICK, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I link that to a specific button field ?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have this code (taken from the BB API doc):

```
FieldChangeListener listener = new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        ButtonField buttonField = (ButtonField) field;
        System.out.println("Button pressed: " + buttonField.getLabel());
    }
};
ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField("Test Button");
buttonField.setChangeListener(listener);
```

Then you can programmatically simulate a click by calling the `fieldChangeNotify(int context)` method of the `buttonField`. Note that you can distinguish normal/real click from a programmatic one by checking the `context` in the `fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`. It is the same context you pass in `fieldChangeNotify(int context)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField("Test Button" ,ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
          buttonField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() 
          {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
            {
                Dialog.alert("Test Button Clicked");

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am not sure what this offers over the answer previously given by Arhimed.

Comment: Perfect ... Dont know who has downvoted it.. Please verify before you down vote.